# SQL calculate average values from numerous fields in table

Tags: sql

I got following table

```
values_table
-------------
created - 02022021
owner - john
value.measure1 - 10
value.measure2 - 2
value.measure3 -7
```

I need to build a query that returns the average value of all fields that starts with 'value.'

So far I managed to write something like this

```
SELECT AVG(
  select * from values_table.columns 
    where column_name like 'value.'
  )
  FROM values_table
```

Comment: Which database are you using? Are your values_table column names crreated, owner, value.measure1, value.measure2 and value.measure3?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN column_name like 'value.%' THEN col2 END)
FROM values_table;
```

Or:

```
SELECT AVG(column_name)
FROM values_table
WHERE column_name like 'value.%';
```